# How did I write this code on react its on javascript ? it says on scrolling the page , navbar sticks at Top

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

This is the js code I want to convert

```
const navbar = document.querySelector("nav");
const navbarOffsetTop = navbar.offsetTop;

window.addEventListener('scroll' , () =>{
    if(window.pageYOffset >= navbarOffsetTop){
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    }else{
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky")
    }
})
```

//here sticky is the css class which says , position="fixed" , top="0"

I tried it but can't figure it our . I want someone who is good in react helps me out from this problem

Comment: React isn't a *language*, it is a *framework*, written in the JavaScript *language*.  "Converting" code from React to JavaScript doesn't make sense; they are the same thing. 
 There isn't anything stopping you from using this code exactly as written in a page that has React elements in it.

Comment: The only significant change would be to not directly manipulate classes, and instead update a state variable which results in an automatic class change. We're not here to do your work for you, though. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to show your attempt. If you're new to React, some training is step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this by the following code inside of the header component:

```js
const Header = () => {
  const [isSticky, setIsSticky] = React.useState(false);
  
  const headerRef = React.useRef();
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const offsetTop = headerRef.current.offsetTop;

    const handleScroll = () => {
      if(window.pageYOffset >= offsetTop){
          setIsSticky(true);
      }else{
          setIsSticky(false);
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll' , handleScroll);
    
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <header className={isSticky ? "sticky" : null} ref={headerRef}>My Header</header>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>

      <Header />

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Also, if you are open to suggestions, maybe you could look into CSS sticky which probably does what you want without any JavaScript: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

Edit: Updated the code to fix problem of keeping stuck

Comment: Thank you brother , It works but , when i scroll up it remains sticks at top the class sticky don't remove . Although It is Much Appreciated That You gave time to this question.

Comment: @Sahilverma that is because the offsetTop changes. Thats my error, I've updated the code.

Comment: Thanks brother , community on @stackoverflow is the best community.